# Loading XML into HTML stored in the local folder

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to load XML document to traverse, can someone please explain why does the below line does not work and a http request has to be made to load the XML document though the XML is stored in the same folder as the HTML.

```
 var xmlDoc = loadXMLDoc("filename.xml")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Security issue, but there are ways to overcome this.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Comment: Thank you all I got know my mistake and understood the concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to read the file back from the server and then render the response. So i would suggest using ajax to do this, then using jQuery to parse the xml

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "filename.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
        // Parse the xml file and get the data 
        // Do what you want here to find the elements in the xml
        var doc = $.parseXML(xml),
            $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    }
});
```